# Enable Minecraft with Parental Controls

Tags: macos, parental-controls, minecraft

My kids (somehow) talked me into installing Minecraft on my iMac. I have separate accounts for them with the Parental Controls feature enabled for each account. When they start up Minecraft on their account it prompts for admin access as expected. If I enter my username/password and click 'Allow Always' the dialog goes away for a couple of seconds then pops back up. If I click 'Allow Once' the games starts up and they can play.

How can I allow them to always play without requiring me to come over and enter my info?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's enough for a proper answer, but you could just extract the minecraft.jar file from the minecraft.zip (or grab it directly from [the website](http://minecraft.net/download), under 'Minecraft for Linux / Other'), and set it up with some kind of launcher so that your kids can run it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and this [thread on Ask Different.se](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62596/parental-controls-always-allow-does-not-work) helped me to solve it. Instead of creating a new script named MyMinecraft as one answer suggested I modified the Java loader.

First I backed up the JavaApplicationStub file. Then I created a new script with that same name and edited the contents to be:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx1024m /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/Resources/Java/MinecraftLauncher.jar
```

Then made that file executable for all users:

```
chmod a+x JavaApplicationStub
```

This allowed Minecraft to load for me without the prompt.

Comment: Unfortunately, this file doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to manually approve the java runtime, and minecraft by going into the preferences and adding it to the list. I'm not sure if the JRE can be individually approved though, but you can always try.